# How to make program output differently depending on number of runs?

Tags: java

This is not like a code help or code review thing.I am trying to make a counter for my program that can define the output of my program.For eg: If i want my program do specific thing after it has been run two times or else it should do another thing.Another example of what i am trying to say is that when i run my program first and second time it should print 3,but when i run it third time it should print 5.
I believe there are many ways already out there,but i don't know how to search such type of specific query on google.

I am working on complex program,where such type of thing is required,but i don't know where and how to start or look.I tried to make a counter,but every time the program runs,it initializes the value of counter and so it doesn't increment.

Comment: Did you look at Random? If random numbers are not what you are looking for, can you write pseudocode to explain what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to maintain a state of the each time it runs. It means in the program, maintain a counter and store it in a file. You can do it in the following way.

1. If there is running state counter stored in a file, it means the application is run first time.
2. Before running the application, read the file which maintains running counter.
3. Based upon the running counter number like even , odd etc, you can write the logic.

Answer (score 2):

You have to save the value in a file or some other storage method that persists after the program runs and ends.

Every time the program runs:

If there's no file, then create one and write the number 1 in it to show that the program has run once.

If there is already a file when you run the program, then read the number stored in it and interpret it as the number of previous runs. Write a number to the file that is 1 higher than the number of previous runs.